# Bypassing the admin priveleges on Mac

Tags: macos, admin

I want to deploy a dmg on Mac OSX and higher. It should not need admin privileges to install the application to the application folder of the system. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dmg is the word you are looking for. If it is an app, you can typically just drag the app to the *Applications* folder.

If you're trying to install something that requires admin privileges and you are physically at the computer, you will need to boot into single user mode with *Command-S*. From single user mode, you are the root user and can do whatever you choose.

Comment: "dmg" is the file name extension for disk images. It's proper in this context.

Comment: I agree to Ken's opinion. I have an application and i want users to install it. Now, many users do not have admin access to the machine, neither do they know about booting into Single User mode with Command-S. So is there any way in which i make a dmg installer and it quietly installs the application without asking for admin privs. Thanks in Advance.